# What did Hegel meant when he said that the universal continually engenders itself while maintaining its identity throughout the process?

Tags: epistemology, political-philosophy, idealism, hegel, marx

The patriotic sentiment acquires its specifically determined content from the various members of the organism of the state. This organism is the development of the Idea to its differences and their objective actuality. Hence these different members are the various powers of the state with their functions and spheres of action, by means of which the universal continually engenders itself, and engenders itself in a necessary way because their specific character is fixed by the nature of the concept. Throughout this process the universal maintains its identity, since it is itself the presupposition of its own production. This organism is the constitution of the state.

1. The patriotic sentiment acquires its specifically determined content from the various members of the organism of the state... These different members are the various powers of the state with their functions and spheres of action.
2. The patriotic sentiment acquires its specifically determined content from the various members of the organism of the state. This organism is the development of the Idea to its differences and their objective actuality ... by means of which the universal continually engenders itself, and engenders itself in a necessary way because their specific character is fixed by the nature of the concept. Throughout this process the universal maintains its identity, since it is itself the presupposition of its own production. This organism is the constitution of the state.

Comment: Hegel here is presenting an anthropomorphic view of the state as a dynamic, evolving entity guided by a fundamental Idea, just like any normal human being, it keeps regenerating itself metabolically via different powers and functions and endeavoring to persist in its own organic being manifested and revealed as its identity, not a mere bundle of separable members...